# How do I get a list of options in an html select using Javascript in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, listbox

- Here is a selector, say `{css: '.quantity'}`.
- I try `driver.findElement({css: '.quantity'});` it finds and returns the listbox
- I see support returning the list of the contents of the `listbox` in a variety of languages (`C#`, `Python` and `Java`), but I see nothing for `Javascript`.

I can get all the options and values of the listbox if I use `driver.findElement({css: '.quantity'}).getAttribute('innerHTML');` but this is a bit of a mess in that it is just a text blob.

I am hoping to iterate the contents of the `listbox` in order to scrape out the values for later use.  I simply want to pass a selector to a `listbox` and get an array of values.  Is there anything easy in `Javascript` for this?

Comment: I think the Java equivalent of what I am looking for is getOptions().

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _Ruby_?

Comment: I am using the Javascript/Node binding of Selenium.  I am trying to get the contents of a listbox.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Node/Javascript documentation on github (http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html), it doesn't seem like the WebElement object has a getOptions() method.

I would recommend just using the findElement**s**({css: 'li'}) method to get the options in an array of WebElements. So your code might looks like this

```
driver.findElement({css: '.quantity'}).findElements({css: 'li'});
```

Comment: `LI`s are not children in an HTML `SELECT`, you would need `OPTION` tags. Also you can combine your two finds into a single CSS selector, `driver.findElement({css: '.quantity option'})`

Comment: So, I tried `li` but instinctively knew it would not work and then tried `option` before reading JeffC's comment.  I am now getting an array of string back ('0', '1', ... length-1 of listbox) , but that's it.  I can't use innerHTML on these objects, even though, looking at the html, there are values.

Comment: Ok, with a little more effort, I was able to get values and innerHTML of the options.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DebanjanB Did you read the actual question title? It states HTML select. The code you posted doesn't confirm anything... it confirms that any element with the `quantity` class was found and that's it. Read OP's comment above if you need any other proof.

Comment: @NA `innerHTML` gets the HTML contained within the element but does not include the HTML of the element itself. Perhaps you want `outerHTML`? See [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) vs [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).